# SharePoint 2013: Download non-text files using REST or JavaScript object model

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have been scratching my head the all thought day figuring out a way to download non-text files like images from host SharePoint web into a App web (SharePoint hosted app).
The code below allows me to get the contents of txt files but when requested for images, I am not able to get the image datauri or contents.

Is this possible via JavaScript/REST to get image contents?

```
var hostweburl,appweburl= null;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//Get the URI decoded URLs.
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(
    getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
    );
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(
    getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
    );

var scriptbase = hostweburl + '/_layouts/15/';
jQuery.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
   function () {
       jQuery.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
           function () { jQuery.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', continueExecution); }
       );
   });

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
        document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}

function continueExecution() {
    var executor;
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    var urlp = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MyAppHost/PublishingImages')/Files('fdef1543-0466-40e5-94b7-35af75ad262d.jpg')/$value?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
    executor.executeAsync(
     {
         url: urlp,
         method: "GET",
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
         contentType: "image/png",
         success: successHandler,
         error: errorHandler,
     });
}

function successHandler(data) {

}

function errorHandler(error) {
}
```

});